# Android: How to stop alarm sound when the app is in background

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an app which plays an alarm sound under specific conditions. Now i would like to give the user a button or something else to stop the alarm even when the app is in the background, so the user doesn't need to reopen the app to stop the alarm. But i have no idea how i can do such a thing... :/

The best thing would be something like a dialog which he can see right on the screen with a stop button or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, [android notifications center](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) it's correct place for the cases. As example you can check Google Maps Navigation App or Waze. It always keep label (e.g. "navigation turned on") in the notification center while running with and button "exit navigation".